# React-table: State doesn't change as expected, and table doesn't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-table

Codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-state-not-updating-hmquq?file=/src/App.js

I am using the [react-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table) package (version 7.1.0).

I have a table which displays some invoices like so:

[image: table example]

The user should be able to select some or all of these items using the `selected` checkbox.

The `selected` field is not part of the data. However, when the user hits a `selected` checkbox, the field should toggle and an array storing document numbers should be populated.

To store the document numbers, I have a stateful getter and setter:

```
const [selectedInvoiceIds, setSelectedInvoiceIds] = useState([]);
```

To populate the field, I am attempting to simply add the document number to the array immutably, from the `onChange` of the checkbox:

```
      {
        Header: "Selected",
        accessor: "selected",
        Cell: item => {
          const { documentNumber } = item.row.values;
          return (
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={selectedInvoiceIds.includes(documentNumber)}
              onChange={() => {
                setSelectedInvoiceIds([...selectedInvoiceIds, documentNumber]);
              }}
            />
          );
        }
      }
```

When a checkbox is clicked for the first time, the `selectedInvoiceIds` becomes populated:

```
selectedInvoiceIds: ["706942"]
```

**The problems are**:

- The table does not update to reflect the state change, despite this prop on the checkbox:

```
checked={selectedInvoiceIds.includes(documentNumber)}
```

- The `selectedInvoiceIds` value gets **overwritten** when another document number is added, instead of being added to, as if the state is re-initialising to `[]` somewhere in between.

Can it be explained why these state issues are occurring and how to get around it?

I am aware of the `useTableState` value exposed by react-table, but I don't know how I can apply it to this use case.

Codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-state-not-updating-hmquq?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues in this code:

```
// 1) updates to state should should use callback function if it uses prv state

 return (
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={selectedInvoiceIds.includes(documentNumber)}
              onChange={() => {
                setSelectedInvoiceIds(prvSelectedInovicesId => [...prvSelectedInovicesId, documentNumber]);
              }}
            />
          );

// 2) also columns is using useMemo, however not providing dependencies, so columns are not being updated when the selectedInvociesIds state gets updated

// 3) you are not yet handling the toggle, this mean you are just always just adding to the array and not removing from it
```

here is a working version code sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-state-not-updating-wkri3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: agree with point 3 - so object would be more reasonable than array,then it can be changed as {...selectedInovicesIds, documentNumber: !selectedInovicesIds[documentNumber]} so it would be enough for toggle

Comment: @DmitryReutov yea an object would be much more better, also in terms of performance, an array means that he is going to do n work for each entry, there are n entries so he is doing n**2 total work. That being said i will even use a Set, as it provides better semantics

Comment: perfomance, i guess, would not worth to be mentioned in this particular case, because even search in 10 000 elements will take such a ridiculously small time on modern devices that user will not notice difference, but object or may be Set is certainly more reasonable for this case

Comment: @DmitryReutov yea i agree, readability is better than performance unless there is already a performance issue, other than that it will be a premature optimization, however i think if the array size is large enough users on mobile devices will notice some sluggishness

Answer (score 1):

Because of useMemo, add your array to last parameter

```
const columns = React.useMemo(
// ....
,
[selectedInvoiceIds]
  );
```

And as we need toggle checkboxed it is more reasonable to keep selected ids in object instead of array and update it as this

```
setSelectedInvoices({
  ...selectedInovicesIds, 
  documentNumber: !selectedInovicesIds[documentNumber]}
)
```

so it will toggle mark